# Pushing a navigation controller is not supported when using MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, messageui

i am geeting crash using this code

Pushing a navigation controller is not supported

```
 MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [messageController setRecipients:recipents];
    [messageController setBody:message];
    [self.parentViewController presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: how you defined your navigation controller?

Comment: first of all i am opening a new view using presentmodelview controller for getting list of contacts, and on this view controller i want to send sms using MFMessageComposeViewController.@Retro

Comment: ContactListController *clc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"clc"];
    UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:clc];
    
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 4):

```
[self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your View is in NavigationController Stack ? Try this-

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:messageController];                          [self.navigationController presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
            [self.parentViewController presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }];

Comment: this worked for me. [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                [self.parentViewController presentViewController:messageInstance animated:YES completion:nil];
            }];

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using `storyboard` or `.xib`, below code helps you.

Add `MessageUI.framework`

write this line for import class.

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

set delegate

```
@interface ListViewController : UIViewController <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

implement following method

```
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
   {
        MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.body = @"Hello...";
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"recipient1, recipient2, recipient3", nil];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        controller.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
}
```

implement its delegate method for dismiss

```
#pragma mark - Message Delegate ============================

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled: break;

        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Sorry, something went wrong, please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        }
        break;

        case MessageComposeResultSent: break;

        default: break;
    }

    [[controller presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible because the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller?language=objc) say that `MFMessageComposeViewController` is a `UINavigationController`

**O-C**

`@interface MFMessageComposeViewController : UINavigationController`

**swift**

`class MFMessageComposeViewController : UINavigationController`